# How do streams internally process data?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have multiple operations being performed on stream, how are they computed internally.

1. Is it computed in the same sequence as that of the input collection?
2. Does it apply function to all the elements and then moves to evaluate the next function ? or it applies  all functions on  one element , then second element ... so on.
3. How is it any different from normal iterations performed on collection in respect of performance.

---

```
    List<Integer> ee = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f1 = x -> x * 2;
    Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f2 = x -> x * x;
    Function<? super Integer, ? extends Integer> f3 = x -> x / 2;
    ee.stream().map(f1.compose(f2.andThen(f3))).collect(Collectors.toList());

    ee.stream().map(f1).map(f2).map(f3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Editin the question to add multiple map operations. How are map functions computed in case of multiple map function application. When talking about non-parallel stream, is the order of computation of elements depends only on the type of input collection (i,e ordered for list, linkedHashmap , sortedset and unordered for hashSet, etc). Also, Can I get some more insights on the internal working of streams so as to  decide better on when are streams not advised to use and when are they advised to be used most.(collection size, nature of sequence, etc, )

Comment: 2. The stream only sees one function. It has no way of decomposing or partially applying it.

Comment: Your title says "2 or more operations" but you are actually only passing one operation to the stream. If you want more, call `map` multiple times. E.g. `map(f1).map(f2).map(f3)`/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Order

> 1. Is it computed in the same sequence as that of the input collection?

Not necessariliy. There are many things that can determine order. On the stream itself, there is `unordered()` and `parallel()` which affect it. Then, you can also influence it with the terminal operation, for example `forEach` vs `forEachOrdered()`. For `collect`, it depends on the underlying `Collection` you are collecting into. For `toList()`, it collects them in the order your stream is currently serving. So if you did not call `unordered()` or anything, it will be ordered.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()):

> Returns a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, in **encounter order**.

---

### Action-Pipeline

> 2. Does it apply function to all the elements and then moves to evaluate the next function ? or it applies all functions on one element , then second element ... so on.

As long as you do not apply a terminal operation, such as `collect`, nothing happens. It memorizes your actions and creates an action-pipe. As soon as you start, by having `collect`, it will iterate all items one after another and apply the full action-pipe to it. So it will take one single element and apply all your functions to it, then stuff it into the resulting list and after that move on to the next element.

However, in your specific case, you only have one single `map(...)` operation. So instead of telling the stream to apply 3 functions, you used the methods in function to compose the 3 functions into one big-function and gave that single function to the stream. So the stream only has one function to work with, which does all your 3 operations one after another, when applied. Usually people go for using multiple `map(...)` calls:

```
ee.stream()
    .map(f1)
    .map(f2)
    .map(f3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

### Performance

> 3. How is it any different from normal iterations performed on collection in respect of performance.

In general, there is more logic attached to streams. You need to construct some objects, Create some action-pipelines etc. So it introduces a bit of overhead, nothing serious though. So as long as you do not have tiny mini data sets and you need every nanosecond, consider it equally good to ordinary iteration.

There are a couple of advantages though. One can be readability (not always of course). And the other prominent advantage is that the Stream API offers multi-threading for free. You just call `parallel()` to suggest the usage and if Java thinks this is a good idea, it will start processing multiple elements at the same time.

Bear in mind though that multi-threading comes with a significant overhead. So if your data source is not big, it might be slower in total.

Comment: Although the above explanation is quite precise, I am still not clear on few points. Edited the question  with more points.. please have a look.. I am looking for answers specific to non-parallel streams only .

Comment: All I said applies for non-parallel streams. So it still holds. Please note that you should not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Prefer to ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Is it computed in the same sequence as that of the input collection?

Yes, because the Spliterator returned by an `ArrayList` is [ordered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#ORDERED):

```
ee.stream().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED); // prints true
```

> 2. Does it apply function to all the elements and then moves to evaluate the next function ? Or it applies all functions on one element, then second element ... so on.

The second one. The Stream doesn't know anything about the internal structure of the mapping function, so it treats it as a single (indivisible) function.

> 3. How is it any different from normal iterations performed on collection in respect of performance.

This was asked many times on StackOverflow. Generally, Streams are a bit slower than their loop counterparts.

Comment: @Zabuza Of course, it's defined. If the Stream is ordered, then the returned List has the same order.

Comment: @Zabuza Javadoc clearly states that: "returns a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, *in encounter order*".

Comment: Agreed. In that case I think your current explanation might be misleading though. Since the implementation could be exchanged at any time. The specification you just shared is the critical part. Just as a note.

Comment: The question “is it computed…” is ambiguous as it’s not clear whether it referers to the processing or the result. The result is guaranteed to be in order, but the processing is intentionally unspecified. To show that the source is ordered, it might be better to use `ee.spliterator()` in the first place rather than `ee.stream().spliterator()`.

Comment: @Holger I hardly imagine a collection where non-parallel processing can be out of order but the final result is in order. I agree that this is an unspecified behavior but in real-world applications, I think we can safely rely on this fact.

Comment: This is not a behavior of the `Collection` but the `Stream` implementation. Yes, currently we can't image it, but some people also couldn't imagine that a future implementation could skip their operations at all (which `count()` may do since Java 9). Also, we already had the phenomenon of operations chained after `flatMap` processing more elements than necessary (while the end result still had the right elements). It's hard to image an operation that benefits from processing out-of-order and reassembling in the right order but never say never...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 2nd point

> (2. Does it apply function to all the elements and then moves to
> evaluate the next function ? or it applies all functions on one
> element , then second element ... so on.)

When the terminal operation is initiated, the stream implementation picks an execution plan. Intermediate operations are divided into stateless (filter(), map(), flatMap()) and stateful (sorted(), limit(), distinct()) operations. A stateless operation is one that can be performed on an element without knowledge of any of the other elements. For example, a filtering operation only needs to examine the current element to determine whether to include or eliminate it, but a sorting operation must see all the elements before it knows which element to emit first.

Reference - https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/articles/j-java-streams-3-brian-goetz/